# Android Studio Layout Inspector doesn't work

Tags: flutter, android-studio, layout-inspector

Layout Inspector doesn't work - the emulated layout is all black or in another case (by resresh) it's all white, while the emulator and the program itself are running.

layout inspector image

[image]

[terminal logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/153jvOq1875DVpXSzgMClAcjLW5EMVz-JfoZVhQGDRAM/edit?usp=sharing)

Versions:

- Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 ,
- Flutter 3.16.0 ,
- Dart 3.2.0,
- SDK Android API 34, extension level 7 Platform,
- Gradle 8.4,
- Kotlin:       1.9.10 ,
- Groovy:       3.0.17 ,
- Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4
  2023,
- JVM:          21.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.1+12-LTS-29),
- OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

I've tried to search the issue by warnings and errors in the terminal, but it didn't help.
The problem is still remaining.